# Amazon Read versus Google Play books

Tags: kindle, epub, drm, google-play-books, send-to-kindle

How does read.amazon.com compare to play.google.com for ebooks?  While I have a Kindle this would lead me more towards Amazon, Google seems to give more full samples and the cloud reader is less laggy.  The flip-side being that converting e-pub to mobi with send-to-kindle doesn't bring all the Kindle lock-in [goodies](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/7723/9853).

Is it largely a matter of picking your DRM poison?

What are costs/difficulties of escaping from either Amazon or Google?